Using vi command line editing, can't backspace before cursor after leaving motion mode
I have a minor but annoying issue that when I press Esc in a terminal to edit my command in the command line in vi motion mode, then move the cursor (like with 'w' to move by a word, or even move the cursor manually with arrow keys or h or l), backspace doesn't work correctly. I can type from the cursor on, and even backspace back to where the cursor began in insert mode, but not before the cursor.
I don't know how to troubleshoot this, so I don't know what would cause this. Is there a fix for this?

It turns out this was a duplicate and was zsh-specific, not bash: (c.f. Backspace in zsh stuck)
Once I edited my .zshrc to have the line bindkey -v '^?' backward-delete-char as suggested in that post, things worked great!
